# Minimal polynomial for a bijective linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ which is not algebraically closed and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.  I am just trying to understand if injectiviity can be used to study the structre of the minimal polynomial of $T$ because none of the theorems from my linear algebra textbook make this notion explicitly clear.

So suppose first that $T$ is a bijection and that $V$ has dimension $1$.  Since $T$ is a bijection can we just fix a $v \in Image (T)$ so that $Tv = av$ for some $a \in F$ and therefore the minmal polynomial of T is just $x-a$. (since $V$ has dimension 1).

> Question: Suppose $dim(V) \ge 2$ if $T$ is a bijection does it follow that the minmal polynomial of $T$ has a linear factor or can we say something stronger?

It is not clear to me at this point if there is a connection between injectivity of a linear operator and diagonaliziablity .

Comment: Are you working over an arbitrary field, or a specific one? Over $\mathbb{C}$, for example, every polynomial splits into linear factors. (And no, there is no connection between injectivity and diagonalisability.)

Comment: @Zhen Thank you for the comment.  I have edited to the post to rule out the trivial case of algebraically closed fields.

Comment: There's one minor connection between the two concepts: if $T$ is *not* injective, then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and thus the minimal polynomial has a linear factor (since $0$ always lies in the underlying field). Of course, this doesn't guarantee that $T$ is diagonalizable, but merely that it has at least one eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move away from algebraically closed fields, the answer is "not in general".
For example, if we work over the real field $\mathbb{R}$, the linear transformation
$: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $T(a,b) = (b,-a)$ has $T^{2} = -I$, and has minimum polynomial $x^{2}+1$, which has no linear factor in $\mathbb{R}[x].$ It is 
also a bijection, as is easily checked.

Comment: @ Geoff Robinson : How to find the minimal polynomial for a transformation? Without computing the matrix?

Comment: @Mathematica: This is possible, though computing that matrix would be the easiest way. For example, in the example above, you can see that $T^{2}(a,b) = (-a,-b)$, so $T^{2} +I =0.$